# box shadows not appearing at the edges

Tags: html, css

I'm working on some css shapes. The problem is when I try to include `box-shadow`, it is going well on the rounded sides but it's not looking good on the other sides.

Here's the output.

[image]

Is there any way to make the shadows follow the border on those 2 other sides?

I used the following code -

```
<style>
.box {
border-radius: 10px 100px / 120px;
            padding: 40px;
            border: none;
            width: 40px; 
            height: 40px;
            box-shadow:  5px -5px 10px #a200a2,
             -5px 5px 10px #a200a2;
background:black;
}
</style>

<div class='box'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`box-shadow` has its limits, but you can achieve it with `drop-shadow()`:

```
filter:
  drop-shadow(0 5px 5px rgba(160, 0, 210, 0.9))
  drop-shadow(0 10px 10px rgba(160, 0, 210, 0.9));
```

> Note: This function is somewhat similar to the `box-shadow` property. The box-shadow property creates a rectangular shadow behind an element's entire box, while the `drop-shadow()` filter function creates a shadow that conforms to the shape (alpha channel) of the image itself.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()

In theory you can also add `::after` positioned bellow with `filter: blur(20px);` and create and tweak your own shadow shape and color.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make an example and noticed that filter does not help here much because of the way how a shadow is formed for such shapes. An alternative I've found for it is the fourth parameter in box-shadow (spread-radius).

> **spread-radius**
> This is a fourth  value. Positive values will cause the shadow to expand and grow bigger, negative values will cause the shadow to shrink. If not specified, it will be 0 (the shadow will be the same size as the element).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow

```css
.shape-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.shape {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 30px 3px 30px 3px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.shape.box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px black;
}


.shape.box-shadow-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
}

.shape.drop-shadow {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-container">
  <span class="shape box-shadow">box-shadow</span>
  <span class="shape box-shadow-2">box-shadow-2</span>
  <span class="shape drop-shadow">drop-shadow</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I too found it.